# What is an up-to-date equivalent of LARTC How-To?

Tags: linux, networking, documentation

The [Linux Advanced Routing and Traffic Control How-To](https://www.lartc.org) was a guide on configuring things like the quality of service modules, iptables, multicasting and IPv6.

Since work stopped on it, Linux has gained network namespaces, programmable classifiers and many other features. The How-To never did include anything on the Layer 7 traffic patch, the web10g patch or other utilities.

Is there a new-and-improved LARTC out there or do people piece together info as they need it?